# EM algorithm R code on Cox PH model with frailty

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, frailty

Let say I have a 'kidney catheter' data set. Data are about the recurrence times to infection, at the point of insertion of the catheter, for kidney patients using portable dialysis equipment. Catheters may be removed for reasons other than infection, in which case the observation is censored. Each patient has exactly 2 observations.

If I want to fit a Cox PH model with random effect (here Gamma frailty) using EM algorithm. By using built in [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) package R code `coxph()`, I can easily do it like this

> ```
> library(survival)
> data(kidney)
> fit<-coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + 
>            frailty(id, dist='gamma', method='em'), kidney)
> ```

But if I want to write a step by step function for EM algorithm, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`coxph()` actually implements a penalised log-likelihood approach which turns out to return the same estimates as the EM algorithm *in the case of gamma frailties* when `method="em"`; see [Therneau and Grambsch (2000, Section 9.6)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+&+health/book/978-0-387-98784-2). (`method` actually refers to the method used to select a solution for theta, the heterogeneity parameter, not to the estimation procedure). Both algorithms are clearly detailed in [Duchateau and Janssen (2008, Chapter 5)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+&+health/book/978-0-387-72834-6). Implementing the EM algorithm might require quite a lot of work, but might be possible following these lines. By the way, there is a SAS macro called `gamfrail` written by Klein that already does the job, even though it is not very user-friendly. It can be downloaded [here](http://www.mcw.edu/FileLibrary/Groups/Biostatistics/Software/SAS_Macro_for_the_Semiparametric_Gamma_Frailty_Model.txt) together with a [guide](http://www.mcw.edu/FileLibrary/Groups/Biostatistics/Software/Quick_Reference_Guide_To_Gamma_Frailty_Macro.txt).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Yes, I'm following the Duchateau and Janssen's book and trying to write function for EM algorithm, really its a critical work. Hope SAS macro will be helpful.